# How to display html text in DevExpress.XtraEditors.RichTextEdit?

Tags: c#, devexpress, richtextbox, xtraeditors

I am having `DevExpress.XtraEditors.RichTextEdit` control in which I want to display html text as readable text. But it show html text as it is with html tag.

How to display html text in `DevExpress.XtraEditors.RichTextEdit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the [RepositoryItemRichTextEdit.DocumentFormat](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemRichTextEdit_DocumentFormattopic) property in the following manner:

```
richTextEdit.Properties.DocumentFormat = DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.DocumentFormat.Html;
richTextEdit.Text = htmlString;
```